# Magento2 - Change customer Group Programatically for guest and logged in users

Tags: magento2, customer-group

I have a form in which when a particular code is given, the customer group should be changed to apply discounts.

I have tried the following code, it changes the customer group. I can see the discounted prices in Product list page as well as Product detail page. But in the cart and checkout process it doesnt apply.

```
$this->session->setCustomerGroupId("3");
```

Can someone please help in solving the issue.

Comment: Hi, I was looking a fix for the same issue, did you finally achieve to do this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->session->setCustomerGroupId("3");
```

This only saves the customer group id in the session (which is temporary). I think in the Checkout, the actual Customers Group ID is used again.

You can set the customers group id (persistent) with the following code:

```
$this->session->getCustomer()->setGroupId("3")->save();
```

You have to make sure, that the customer is logged in before. You can check that with the following:

```
$this->session->isLoggedIn()
```

Comment: Thanks David, I would like to change that for guest customer as well and i do not want to change the customer group permanently. I just want to change the group until the customer orders something or the session expires.

Comment: ok, this will not work with the customer group since a guest is not a customer yet, it gets always the NOT_LOGGED_IN group while customers always get the one from db. You should use coupon codes btw, they already do what you are trying to achieve; enter a code and get a discount

Comment: I don't think $this->session->setCustomerGroupId("3") actually does anything. It does mark the session data but any tier prices for customer group 3 are not used and if they register they are registered as a general user.